# How to find the maximun value in a dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```js
let highest_prob_list = {
   "hi": 100,
   "bye": 1,
};
```

I need to find the key with the greatest value in the dictionary.

For example, I would like `"hi"` from the object above.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: By iterating over it

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the properties of the object, then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over the array to get the property with the highest value.

```js
let obj = {
   "hi": 100,
   "bye": 1,
};

let props = Object.keys(obj)
const res = props.reduce((a,b) => a = obj[b] > obj[a] ? b : a, props[0])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const findMax = () => {
  const highest_prob_list = {
    "hi": 100,
    "bye": 1,
  }
  const keys = Object.keys(highest_prob_list)

  let max = keys[0]

  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (highest_prob_list[key] > highest_prob_list[max]) {
      max = key;
    }
  })

  return max;
}
```